# multi_index query [WHERE]

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

How do we query tables in EOS? Specifically like the WHERE clause in SQL Database?

I see examples that uses iterator to find if the record exists, however I don't see it as the right approach specially if we have large sets of data.

I can use get and find for the primary key, but what about for other keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use primary key or index to query the data.

For the query where, the index provide find and lower_bound and upper_bound method, which returns the iterator, if you have more than one rows, just use code like it below:

```
while(iter != xxx.end()) {
   iter++;
}
```

for lower_bound or upper_bound, or

```
while(iter != xxx.end() && iter->yourdata == yourquery) {
   iter++;
}
```

for find.

Comment: I think the second condition needs to be != aswell. Otherwise the loop will just check the first element and finish then.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 if you use find method, means that you want to get all the same data with your query, so use ==

Comment: Yes but the index needs to be build on that value to use find. If you want to query a value the index is not build upon you can't use find and this condition because the loop will be likely to stop after the first element. So maybe the code/answer should get some context.

Comment: I see, so there's really no way for us to avoid the use of iterator for this kind situation? Thanks!